# PayPal handling of subscr_eot if user switch to different subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

Here is the scenario:

- on 25/3 user purchases a basic monthly subscription (recurring payment profile)
- on 7/4 user cancels basic monthly subscription and start a premium monthly subscription (a different recurring payment profile)

Now my question is whether I am going to receive a "subscr_eot" on the 25/4 (referring to the first basic monthly subscription) or is PayPal smart enough not to send subscr_eot since the user has started a new recurring payment profile with me?

I would like to set the user profile to "no subscription" as soon as I get a "subscr_eot", but I am not sure whether I can trust PayPal to notice that a new subscription was started between cancellation and end_of_term.

Answer (score 0):

If it's canceled then the end of term was never reached.  In such a case you'd get an IPN with txn_type=subscr_cancel.  You would then get another IPN with txn_type=subscr_signup when the new profile is created.

That is assuming you're using standard subscriptions.  You specifically mentioned subscr_eot, so that's why I made that assumption.  However, you also mentioned "recurring payment profile".  The Recurring Payments API is separate from standard subscriptions and would have different txn_type values for IPN, so if that's what you're actually using you'll need to adjust accordingly.